# 2gb table with 10 million rows, late pagination select is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have table in MySQL with 10 million rows with 2 GB data 
selecting IN LIFO format  data is slow

**Table engine** is = `InnoDB`

table has one **primary key** and one **unique key**

```
SELECT * FROM link LIMIT 999999 , 50;
```

how I improve the performance of the table. ?

**table structure**

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
url varchar(255)    NO  UNI NULL    
website varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
state   varchar(10) NO      NULL    
type    varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
prio    varchar(100)    YES     NULL    
change  varchar(100)    YES     NULL    
last    varchar(100)    YES     NULL
```

**NOTE:** 
`SELECT * FROM link LIMIT 1 , 50;` is taking `.9ms` but current sql is taking `1000ms` its 1000 time taking more

Comment: Do you need all the columns from the table?Can you elaborate on slowness- How long is it taking? Also what is the data type of the columns?

Comment: can you run below query and paste the result

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM link LIMIT 999999 , 50;`

Comment: its nearly take 1 sec but when no of row will be more bigger then time fetching time  will be more  

SELECT * FROM link LIMIT 1 , 50; is taking  .9ms but  current sql is taking 1000ms its 100 time taking more.

Comment: 1,000,000,000,000 rows stored in 5 GB, that's 200 rows per byte, amazing. So what's the actual number/sizer?

Comment: 10005491 row with ~2GB but growing very fast. so

Comment: Have a look at [Pagination Done the Right Way](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way). He is using Postgres for illustration, but the main idea is to use a suitable index, which should be applicable for MySQL as well.

Comment: I've edited the title of this question, and the first sentence.. seems like you are confused about what a trillion is. Also much better to ask the question as the problem is and include additional concerns (It is growing) part in the details rather than exaggerate.

Comment: What is the cardinality of website and url? What is the cardinality of state,type,prio?  What is stored in change and last? Dates?

Comment: And you are really sitting there clicking on the [Next] button 20,000 times?  I think not.  And without an `ORDER BY`, you can't be guaranteed to get any particular 50 rows!

Comment: some how I have to access data from DB from any reason

Answer (score 7):

This most likely is due to "early row lookup"

MySQL can be forced to do "late row lookup". Try below query

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    link
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 999999 , 50
        ) q
JOIN    link l
ON      l.id = q.id
```

Check this article

[MySQL limit clause and rate low lookups](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

Comment: I didn't believe that, until testing it myself. In my test it was 50% performance win. Why MySQL still can not optimize such queries without help?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: It was a surprise for me too when I first encountered it.

Answer (score 6):

For the *Next* and *Prev* buttons you can use a `WHERE` clause instead of `OFFSET`.

**Example** (using `LIMIT 10` - Sample data explained below): You are on some page which shows you 10 rows with the ids `[2522,2520,2514,2513,2509,2508,2506,2504,2497,2496]`. This in my case is created with

```sql
select *
from link l
order by l.id desc
limit 10
offset 999000
```

For the next page you would use

```sql
limit 10
offset 999010
```

getting rows with ids `[2495,2494,2493,2492,2491,2487,2483,2481,2479,2475]`.

For the previous page you would use

```sql
limit 10
offset 998990
```

getting rows with ids `[2542,2541,2540,2538,2535,2533,2530,2527,2525,2524]`.

All above queries execute in *500 msec*. Using the "trick" suggested by Sanj it still takes *250 msec*.

Now with the given page with `minId=2496` and `maxId=2522` we can create queries for the *Next* and *Last* buttons using the `WHERE` clause.

Next button:

```sql
select *
from link l
where l.id < :minId -- =2496
order by l.id desc
limit 10
```

Resulting ids: `[2495,2494,2493,2492,2491,2487,2483,2481,2479,2475]`.

Prev button:

```sql
select *
from link l
where l.id > :maxId -- =2522
order by l.id asc
limit 10
```

Resulting ids: `[2524,2525,2527,2530,2533,2535,2538,2540,2541,2542]`.

To reverse the order you can use the query in a subselect:

```sql
select *
from (
    select *
    from link l
    where l.id > 2522
    order by l.id asc
    limit 10
) sub
order by id desc
```

Resulting ids: `[2542,2541,2540,2538,2535,2533,2530,2527,2525,2524]`.

These queries execute in "no time" (less than 1 msec) and provide the same result.

You can not use this solution to create page numbers. But i don't think you are going to output 200K page numbers.

**Test data:**

Data used for the example and benchmarks has been created with

```sql
CREATE TABLE `link` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `website` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `prio` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `change` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `url` (`url`)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into link
    select i.id
        , concat(id, '-', rand()) url
        , rand() website
        , rand() state
        , rand() `type`
        , rand() prio
        , rand() `change`
        , rand() `last`
    from test._dummy_indexes_2p23 i
    where i.id <= 2000000
      and rand() < 0.5
```

where `test._dummy_indexes_2p23` is a table containing 2^23 ids (about 8M). So the data contains about 1M rows randomly missing every second id. Table size: 228 MB

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my SQL  Query to this and this is taking less amount of time.

```
 SELECT * FROM link ORDER BY id LIMIT 999999 , 50  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the large amount of data,

There are few tips for improve the query response time:

1. Change the storage engine Innodb to myisam.
2. Create table partitioning 
   (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-management.html)
3. Mysql cluster (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-overview.html)
4. Increase hardware capacity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all running on your table without any order doesn't guaranty your query will return the same data if ran twice.
It's better adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Taking `id` as a good candidate, as it's your primary key and seems unique (as it's an `auto_increment` value).

You could use this as your base:

```
SELECT * FROM link ORDER BY id LIMIT 50;
```

This will give you the first 50 rows in your table.

Now for the next 50 rows, instead of using `OFFSET`, we could save our last location in the query.

You would save the id from the last row last id from the previous query and use it in the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM link WHERE id > last_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 50;
```

This will give you the next 50 rows after the last id.

The reason your query runs slowly on high values of `OFFSET` is because mysql has to run on all rows in the given `OFFSET` and return the last `LIMIT` number of rows. This means that the bigger `OFFSET` is the slower the query will run.

The solution I showed above, doesn't depend on `OFFSET`, thus the query will run at the same speed independent of the current page.

See also this useful article that explains a few other options you can choose from: http://www.iheavy.com/2013/06/19/3-ways-to-optimize-for-paging-in-mysql/